# Laravel package whoops exception

Tags: laravel, exception, whoops

In my Laravel package I have this code:

```
try {
    $var_msg = "Exception example";
    throw new InvalidNameException($var_msg);
}
catch (InvalidNameException $e) {
    abort(403, $e->getMessage());
    //report($e);Exception Log
}
```

The error is displayed as html error page. But, I'd like to report the error as an whoops error.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Do you have ```"filp/whoops"``` package installed in your project?

Comment: That's already included automatically with Laravel

Comment: This _is_ the whoops error. See https://laravel-news.com/whoops-laravel-5-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this code as reference.

```
    $whoops = new \Whoops\Run();
    $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());

    // Set Whoops as the default error and exception handler used by PHP:
    $whoops->register();

    throw new \RuntimeException("Oopsie!");
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

So it is absolutely sufficient:
throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage());

Comment: @whollaus Did you managed to do it with ```InvalidNameException ```?

Comment: yes, like this:
try {
    $var_msg = "Exception example";
    throw new InvalidNameException($var_msg);
}
catch (InvalidNameException $e) {
    throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage()); 
    //report($e);Exception Log
}

Comment: @whollaus Is it coming as ```Whoops``` format error.